# differences between ゆっくり and 遅く

Tags: meaning, adverbs

what is the difference between the use of ゆっくり and おそい especially talking about adverbs, for example:

> ゆっくり歩いてください

> 遅く歩いてください

The second one sounds weird for me, but I dont understand the reason behind or when to use one or the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

遅い has negative connotations when used to describe someone’s movement or action. It’s like saying “not quick enough”. For example, the following statement sounds like a criticism.

> 彼は歩くのが遅い。

This negative sense is clearer in the following.

> 彼は仕事が遅い。

ゆっくり has no such connotations in itself. If it’s used in a criticism, that’s due to sarcasm.

Maybe that’s why 遅く歩いてください sounds weird.